# AWS ApiGateway: invalid mapping expression parameter in GUI

Tags: aws-api-gateway

through `AWS ApiGateway GUI` I'm configuring HTTP Header for `IntegrationRequest`.
I have a simple GET method (with header "Accept") whose call flow is:
[image]

When trying to map the `Accept header` in the integration request I get the error:

[image]

Do you have any suggestions, please?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that in GUI you need to write **'method.request.header.accept'** (with quote).

[image]

Comment: This will prevent using the actual header from the context, and instead, it will be a literal replacement of the Accept header. It should be without single quotes.